# How does the attitude and heading reference (AHRS) work on Boeing 737 aircraft?

Tags: navigation, boeing-737, heading, inertial-nav-system, attitude

I would like to know how the AHRS work on Boeing 737 aircraft. If this aircraft (like every the other ones I guess) has an Inertial Reference System (IRS), composed of 3 accelerometers and 3 gyroscopes, what elements compose its AHRS? 
3 accelerometers and 3 gyroscopes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 737 does not have a separate AHRS. Those functions are simply outputs from the two IRS's.

[image]
([Source](http://www.b737.org.uk/navigation.htm)) 737 IRS panel.

ATT (attitude) mode selects the *AHRS-only output* of the IRS.

Comment: Thank you for this info! What I am actually trying to figure out is Boeing's flight management system's "architecture" i.e.: does it use GPS, does it use radio navigation, does it use AHRS, automatic compass, etc... Any idea about how I can find that out?

Comment: @traducerad  For a good description, check out this document from SmartCockpit.com.  [Flight Management and Navigation](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/B737NG-Flight_Management_and_Navigation.html)  It's a bit long to try and summarize here.